# Octave and SWIG. mkoctfile complains: unrecognized argument

Tags: c++, swig, octave, quantlib

I am in the process of writing a lightweight Octave binding to Quantlib, using SWIG and mkoctfile. I am following the documentation found on the SWIG and Octave homepage.

From the SWIG documentation:

> **27.2.1 Compiling a dynamic module**
>
> Octave modules are DLLs/shared objects having the ".oct" suffix.
>   Building an oct file is usually done with the mkoctfile command
>   (either within Octave itself, or from the shell). For example,
>
> $ swig -octave -c++ example.i -o example_wrap.cxx $ mkoctfile
>   example_wrap.cxx example.c
>
> where example.c is the file containing the gcd() implementation.

These are the files I have so far:

- my SWIG interface file quantlib-octave.i
- my function implementations quantlib-octave.cpp
- a glue wrapper file generated using SWIG: quantlib-octave_wrap.cxx

This is the CLI output when I invoked mkoctfile:

> root@yourbox:~/src/quantlib-octave$ mkoctfile quantlib-octave_wrap.cxx
>   quantlib-octave.cpp mkoctfile: unrecognized argument
>   quantlib-octave_wrap.cxx

The help information displayed when I type `mkoctfile -h` is not very useful.

Does anyone know why mkoctfile is complaining?

**Version Info**

```
SWIG Version 2.0.4
Compiled with g++ [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
Configured options: +pcre

mkoctfile, version 3.6.0

Octave: 3.6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by renaming the extension of the generated file from .cxx to .cpp.

Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: The better solution looks to me to be patching mkoctfile to be less picky.